# Sinon stub body code?

Tags: sinon

odd.  if I stub a method and try to look at the stub, I don't see it.  how can this be???

```
var myclass = {
    mymethod: function( console.log('ok'); }
};

var mym = sinon.stub(myclass, 'mymethod');
console.log(mym.toString());
console.log(myclass.mymethod.toString());
```

what I get in the above is:

> mym
>
> mym

but I expected to see the body of the replacement function! what's going on here?

Comment: Try logging `myclass.mymethod.name`.

Comment: that returns 'proxy'

Comment: That's a hint that it's a stub and not the original.

Comment: yes, I get that, but I would have expected: `function proxy() {}`, no? it is a function, even if empty

Comment: Well no, the name of the function would show just that: the name of the function. But I think it's perfectly valid to override a function's `toString()` method so it would return an empty string (or whatever else you'd want).

Comment: but I'm not printing the name of the function.  I'm stringifying the function.  as for overriding the stringifier, I guess it could be done, but why would sinon do that?  returning the function name instead of its body is substantially less useful

Comment: Why would you need the function body for a stubbed function?

Comment: well, it's useful to know what the function is doing

Comment: Do you have a specific use-care for this? Or do you just want to know how sinon stubs work?

Comment: I wanted to know how it could be that the stub was actually a function but I couldn't see its body.  now I'd like to know why sinon overrides the .toString() to return only the body name (since that seems to be what's happening)

Comment: [This](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/blob/master/lib/sinon/util/core/function-to-string.js) is what Sinon replaces `toString()` with.

Comment: yes, I see.  pity there are no comments in the code to indicate why they did that.  oh well.  thanks for walking with me a bit